# progressDialog gets dismissed before fragment opened up

Tags: java, android, fragment, progressdialog

I was having some problem when trying to dismiss ProgressDialog after opened up a new fragment. Here is my code:

```
        ProgressFragment progressDialog = new ProgressFragment();
        progressDialog.setProgressMessage("Sending command, please wait.");
        progressDialog.show(fragment.getFragmentManager(), null);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(() -> {
            if (true) {
                ResultFragment resultFragment = new ResultFragment_();
                resultFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            else{
                // show error toast
            }
        }, 5000);
```

With the code above, the progressDialog got dismissed before the new fragment opened up. Is there any way to set it such that the new fragment opened up, then dismiss the progress dialog.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Very easy Idea is send the message through handler to Activity and close progress-dialog. Like,

**Fragment OnCreate**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   Message msg = new Message();
   msg.what = 1223;
   Activity1.mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

}
```

**in Activity**

```
 public static Handler mHandler = new Handler(new Handlercontext.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessagegetClass(Message msg) {

     if(msg.what == 1223){
          progressDialog.dismiss();
     }

     return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry but what I am trying to do is in first fragment, I opened up progressDialog. Then when switching over to fragment 2, I dismiss the progressDialog after fragment 2 shows up

Comment: you can apply this logic for that.

Comment: hyperfkck, remove `progressDialog.dismiss()` from your code and add this code.

Answer (score 0):

Declare in Fragment A

```
private ProgressFragment progressDialog;
```

and

```
public void CloseProgressFragment()
{
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

**do not** dismiss the dialog in postDelayed

in Fragment B get your Fragment A with the help of the FragmentManager and call the method to close

```
string fragATag = typeof(FragmentA).Name

FragmentA fragmentA = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(fragATag);

fragmentA.CloseProgressFragment();
```

Comment: I do not think 'var' is supported in Android java :(

Comment: This code is Xamarin.Android. But i think it shows the main idea to solve your problem. Declare a public method to close the dialog and get your Fragment A in Fragment B (i think it is easy to find a way to do this in java). Then call the public method to close it